# mailx is working to send mails to external network. But mutt is not working?

Tags: postfix, smtp, sendmail, mutt

I have a server with postfix service running.

I am able to send mails to external network using mailx.

But with mutt, I can only send mails to users inside network.

What I might be the issue?

From /var/log/mailog, I can see that in both the cases (mutt & mailx), the message is sent.

`Oct 22 00:25:31 myserver postfix/smtp[7364]: 905ED140D50: to=<abcd@***.com>, relay=*****.**.***-intra.net[10.150.129.55]:25, delay=1.2, delays=0.46/0.03/0.47/0.27, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 t9LLPV2P011388 Message accepted for delivery)`

Neither any error registered in logs nor there is Delivery Failed acknowledgement in /var/mail/user.

But, previously, I did get Delivery Failed acknowledgement when relay host was not set in main.cnf. After setting relay host, no error messages, but no delivery.And if I don't set relay host, even mailx won't work.

Is this due to firewall, mailx command is anyhow working right?

If too many questions, please answer only the first one.
Everything is big confusion.

Need to go through all the concepts. But trying my luck here if I can get an answer or suggestions quickly.

Comment: Both `mutt` and `mailx` should be default drop messages off to the local `sendmail` binary, so I'd check what `mutt` is setting as a `from` address versus what `mailx` sets, for starters.

Comment: Have you checked `from=` log lines? Does both use the same envelope sender email address?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip in mailx I have mentioned the from address like abc@xyz.com....for mutt, it is automatically taking username@servername.x.y.z